# ASP.NET configuration using cassini instead of IISExpress

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASPNET MVC application that I have configured to use IISExpress.
If I go to Project --> ASP.NET configuration, Visual Studio seems to fire up Casssini anyways for the admin configuration pages. Is there a way to change this to use IISExpress

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this happens when you have more than one website project in your solution.  Is that the case here?  If so, you have to set IISExpress as the server for all projects.

Comment: No. I have a single web project in the solution.

Comment: Oh, I get you now.  The ASP.NET Web Site Configuration tool always runs under Cassini.  Nothing you can do about that.